# How are apps white/black listed in a corporate owned device (DevicePolicyManger)

Tags: android, device-policy-manager, device-owner

I've studied the source code (and what little documentation there is) for the Google sample app which demonstrates the use of the DevicePolicyManger class to set up a corporate owned device. 
(https://developer.android.com/samples/DeviceOwner/index.html)

And have also successfully configured a device such that this app is the device owner for the device.

However I can't find any documentation nor code related to how to set which apps are enabled or disabled by default.

Comment: If you are using Android 5.0 - Android for Work uses profiles to restrict apps: https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't anything in there that lists a certain app or set of apps being excluded or included.

Comment: Read about managed profiles: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise specifically: "By default, only a small subset of apps are enabled in the managed profile."

Answer (score 0):

Using [DevicePolicyManager#setApplicationHidden](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) class you can set apps to be hidden from the user on that profile using apps packages.

To be able to list what is hidden and what is not, I do it from `adb`.

List all active pacakges:

`adb shell pm list packages`

List all packages including uninstalled but with local files (hidden):

`adb shell pm list packages -u`

I have this alias to show me only hidden packages:

`alias adb_hidden_packages='fgrep -v -f <(adb shell pm list packages |sort) <(adb shell pm list packages -u|sort)'`

Comment: Do this answer the question?